# One to Many relationship for Images in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use SQL Server. At the moment I have two tables in my Data Base.

One table is `CmsContents` which represents pages for my blog, the second table is called `CmsImagesContents` which is collecting information about images associated with a specific page.

The relationship between the two tables is of type `One to Many`, one page can have many images but one image can have only one page.

I understand this design is pretty straightforward and I started to realize some limitations, here my questions:

- I need to add an image to my database before associating it with a page, I'm not a big fan of NULL values. What are the options available in my design?
- Would you suggest my design for this scenario? Do you know a better alternative?

Thanks for your help!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CmsImagesContents](
   [ImageContentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,   
   [ContentId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [RowGuid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,   
   [Title] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
   [AltTag] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
   [Caption] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
   [CopyrightNote] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,  

   CONSTRAINT [PK_CmsImagesContents_ImageContentId]
   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ImageContentId] ASC)
)


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CmsImagesContents] WITH CHECK 
 ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CmsImagesContents_ContentId]
  FOREIGN KEY([ContentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CmsContents] ([ContentId])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an intersecting table.  If I was naming the tables they would be named

```
    Content
    --------
    ContentID (PK)
    Title
    Text
    etc...

    Image
    -----
    ImageID (PK)
    Size
    Title
    etc....

    ContentImages
    --------------
    ContentImagesID (PK)
    ContentID
    ImageID
```

And now add a unique constraint on the imageID in ContentImages (so it can only appear in the intersecting)table once)

Now you can add content and images as you wish and then associate an image to content by populating the intersecting table

Comment: Thanks Andrew .. you approach make sense in my context!